# If checkbox checked do something else uncheck

Tags: c#, if-statement, events, checkbox

I am trying to create an if statement to prompt me asking if i am sure i want to check the checkbox. If the checkbox is already checked to just uncheck the box. Below is what i have an cant seem to get to work. Thanks! if anyone has a simple way of doing this please advise.

```
if (checkBox15.Checked == false)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to check this?", "Prompt", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
    { 
        Updatelist(); 
    } 
    else
    {
        checkBox15.Checked = false;
        return;
    }  
}
else  if (checkBox15.Checked == true)
{
    checkBox15.Checked = false;
    return;
}
```

Comment: In what event is your code? What UI are you using? windows forms?

Comment: This is on MouseClick event.

Answer (score 4):

You have missed `if(`

```
if(MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to check this?", 
    "Prompt", 
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
    MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
{ 
    Updatelist(); 
}
else
{
    checkBox15.Checked = false;
    return;
}
```

Comment: this also depends on *where* this method is called. if inside check changed event handler, this will create infinite recursion -> stackoverflow. you may need, in this case, use some boolean switch.

Comment: @Tigran it is creating a recursion. Any suggestion on how a switch would look?

Comment: @hexc: create a instance boolean, that switches value (say becomes true)  *before* checkBox15.Checked = false;. And in event handler check if that boolean is true, set it to false (reset it to original value) and return, so do not process anything as that even was fired due the checkBox15.Checked = false; code.

Answer (score 0):

This Is Your Answer

```
if (checkBox15.IsEnabled == false)
{
MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to check this?", "Prompt",    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
{ 
    Updatelist(); 
} 
else
{
    checkBox15.IsEnabled = false;
    return;
}  
}`enter code here`
else  if (checkBox15.IsEnabled == true)
{
checkBox15.Checked = false;
return;
```